# Validation and htmlAttributes argument of Html.DropDownList

Tags: c#, validation, webmatrix, asp.net-webpages

The following allows you to specify a htmlAttribute to get additional html attributes added to a <select> item.

```
public IHtmlString DropDownList(string name, IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes);
public IHtmlString DropDownList(string name, IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList, object htmlAttributes);
```

I have used the following, cribbed from questions on SO and others to good effect:

```
<fieldset name="vehicleIdFieldSet">
    <label for="vehicleSelectControl">Choose Vehicle</label>
    @{
        var htmlAttributes = new { id = "vehicleSelectControl", 
                                style = "font-size:24px;",
                                };

        string string_htmlAttributes = "";
        foreach (PropertyDescriptor property in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(htmlAttributes))
        {
            string_htmlAttributes += string.Format("{0}=\"{1}\" ", property.Name.Replace('_', '-'), property.GetValue(htmlAttributes));
        }
    }
    @Html.DropDownList("vehicleId", listVehicles, string_htmlAttributes) 
    @Html.ValidationMessage("vehicleId")
</fieldset>
```

I want to add `Validation.ClassFor("vehicleId")` to the attributes.  I can't seem to get this to work, partly because the htmlAttribute fails to instantiate when the value of a property is null.  Also because `class` is a reserved word, but I think I have a workaround for that.

Doesn't work: ClassFor returns null

```
var htmlAttributes = new { id = "vehicleSelectControl", 
                        style = "font-size:24px;",
                        @class = Validation.ClassFor("vehicleId").ToString()
```

Doesn't work: Still null

```
string className = Validation.ClassFor("vehicleId").ToString();
var htmlAttributes = new { id = "vehicleSelectControl", 
                        style = "font-size:24px;",
                        @class = className
                        };
```

Doesn't work: Still null, shouldn't be

```
string className = (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Validation.ClassFor("vehicleId").ToString())) ? "" : Validation.ClassFor("vehicleId").ToString();

var htmlAttributes = new { id = "vehicleSelectControl", 
                        style = "font-size:24px;",
                        @class = className
                        };
```

Should I just give up, or is there a way to have my <select> styled by validation?